# Windows 8.1 how to make start screen showing only apps?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, start-screen

When I install an application in the start screen appears a lot of useless shortcuts, like help, web links, uninstall etc. Is there a way to make the start screen showing only application (executable file only)?

Answer (score 1):

[StartIsBack(+)](http://startisback.com/) has an option to Rename `Start` to `Apps` and this only shows Apps.

> Rename Start Screen to "Apps" and keep only modern apps there.